# ERROR SUBDOMAIN DOES NOT REDIRECT IN NGINX

Tags: nginx, server

I have a domain like www.app.com and a subdomain like www.server.app.com

I just configure my sites-available, sites-enabled and hosts but my error is when I try to acced to subdomain, always redirect to domain. This is my code:

SERVER | SUBDOMAIN

```
upstream server.app.com {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  root /var/www/server.app.com/html;
  server_name server.app.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/server.app.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/server.app.error.log debug;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

DOMAIN

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app.com;
    return       301 http://www.app.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/app.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.app.com;

    location / {
       # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What is wrong, I have the same in other app and is good? thanks in advance

Comment: why is this tagged `javascript`? by the way, that `upstream` configuration does nothing, since you never use it for your proxy_pass config

Comment: You have no server block for `www.server.app.com` so it will use the `default_server`.

Comment: @RichardSmith so wat do I have to do

Comment: If the subdomain is accessed using the hostnames `server.example.com` and `www.server.example.com` than you must list them in the `server_name` directive. For example: `server_name server.example.com www.server.example.com;`

Comment: I don;t understad :(